# ¿Es correcto el uso de "haciendo que"?

Tags: gramática

Esta frase fue traducida de inglés y pienso que la frase *haciendo más fácil* es un caso de anglicismo. ¿Es usada correctamente aquí?

> Las diferencias en el diseño emparejado tienen menos variabilidad que
>   las medidas individuales en el diseño completamente aleatorizado,
>   **haciendo más fácil** detectar una diferencia en el pulso medio para los
>   dos tratamientos.

Esta oración es de un texto sobre la estadística. Por eso, las palabras como "tratamientos", "diseño emparejado" y "diseño aleatorizado" son usadas. El término "diseño aleatorizado" es diferente que "diseño aleatorio".

---

Is the phrase *haciendo más fácil* used correctly above? I believe it is badly translated from the English version.

Comment: He visto tantas veces la frase que no me suena nada extraño.  Creería que es correcta.  Sin embargo _‘facilitando’_ sería una mejor traducción.  Me suena más extraño lo de _‘diseño emparejado‘_ y _‘diseño aleatorizado’_ (sobre todo ese _aleatorizado_, ¿no sería mejor _aleatorio_?) y la palabra _‘tratamientos’_ en este contexto.

Comment: la frase es chunga de verdad... ;)

Comment: El gerundio "haciendo" tampoco es muy correcto en este caso, aunque frecuente. http://manualdeestilo.rtve.es/el-lenguaje/6-5-los-verbos/6-5-2-el-gerundio-normas-de-uso/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo creo que es totalmente correcto, de hecho es de las pocas partes de tu frase que suenan normal :)

El uso de las expresiones `hacer más fácil` y `hacer más difícil` es perfectamente válido y, de hecho, es muy común. Es cierto que podrías usar los verbos `facilitar` y `dificultar`, pero no creo que una opción sea más correcta que la otra... Incluso podrías usar `haciendo que sea/resulte más fácil`...

Coincido con el comentario de @CarlosEugenio en que lo que realmente suena raro en esa frase es lo de `diseño emparejado` y `diseño aleatorizado`. De hecho, el vocablo `aleatorizado` no está recogido en el diccionario, por lo que probablemente deberías usar `aleatorio`...

Tampoco me suena bien el uso de `tratamientos`, donde probablemente quedaría mejor usar algo como `modelos` o `metodologías`, aunque sería necesario más contexto...

Por último, sinceramente tampoco entiendo qué quieres decir con `pulso medio`, aunque, de nuevo, necesitaría más contexto...

Comment: Dado que parece un texto médico, supongo que el `pulso medio` es el valor medio del pulso de una persona.